# Jquery window.open em "success" no ajax está sendo bloqueado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Gostaria que ao salvar um input e atualizar o div com a nova informação, na mensagem de retorno "success" do ajax, fizesse também a impressão do div. Exemplo

```
success :  function(response){                  
 $("#containerResultado").html(response);
 var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divresultado');
            var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
            popupWin.document.open();
            popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geralmente os navegadores bloqueiam o método `window.open` quando não é uma ação direta do usuário. Uma solução seria abrir a janela antes de chamar o AJAX e após a resposta do AJAX manipulá-la, seria algo parecido com isso:

```
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');

$.ajax({
    type: "...",
    url: ...,
    data: ...,
    contentType: "...",
    dataType: "...",
    success: function(response){                  
      $("#containerResultado").html(response);
      var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divresultado');
      popupWin.document.open();
      popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + 
      divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
      popupWin.document.close();
},
    error: function (response) {
      popupWin.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Tive a ideia de fazer com iframe que para o meu caso funciona até melhor: 
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe> 

`var newWin = window.frames["printf"];
newWin.document.write('<body onload="window.print()">dddd</body>');
newWin.document.close();`